Perform an SQL 'database.exec()' search in a function not under a FastAPI decorator
I am trying to streamline a FastAPI endpoint being developed by my team, in which we are repeatedly registering items to an SQL database if they don't already exist in it.
The session was defined in one file as follows:
from functools import partial

from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine
from fastapi import Depends

def get_db_session() -> Session:  # type: ignore
    _url = "postgresql+psycopg2://some-path:8000"
    engine = create_engine(_url)
    with Session(engine) as session:
        try:
            yield session
        finally:
            session.close()

our_db_session = partial(get_db_session, some_config_file)
our_db: Session = Depends(our_db_session)

It is then imported for use in the file where the database lookups are happening:
from fastapi import APIRouter

from other_file import our_db

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/register_file/")
def register_file(
    file_name: Path,
    search_criteria: Union[int, str],
    db: Session = our_db,
):
    db_entry = db.exec(
        select(Table1)
        .where(Table1.file_name==file_name)
        .where(Table1.some_value==search_criteria)
    ).one()

When placed inside the decorated function, the lookup works without issue. However, as there are many such functions registering different things, and the lookup criteria is the same, it got repetitive typing the same thing over and over again within the decorated functions. As such, I tried to move the lookup function into a separate function that gets called within the decorated functions:
def get_db_entry(
    file_name: Path,
    search_criteria: Union[str, int],
    db: Session = our_db,
):
    db_entry = db.exec(
        select(Table1)
        .where(Table1.file_name==file_name)
        .where(Table1.some_value==search_criteria)
    ).one()
    return db_entry

@router.post("/register_file/")
def register_file(
    file_name: Path,
    search_criteria: Union[int, str],
    db: Session = our_db,
):
    db_entry = get_db_entry(file_name=file_name, search_criteria=search_criteria)

However, when I do it like that, I get an error saying that "Depends" does not have the attribute ".exec()".
I'm very new to FastAPI and SQL, so I would greatly appreciate advice on why this doesn't work, and what I need to change in order to migrate the search function out of the decorated function.

You should remove  = our_db from the signature of get_db_entry function and pass this parameter explicitly when you call it:
def get_db_entry(
    file_name: Path,
    search_criteria: Union[str, int],
    db: Session,
):
    db_entry = db.exec(
        select(Table1)
        .where(Table1.file_name==file_name)
        .where(Table1.some_value==search_criteria)
    ).one()
    return db_entry

@router.post("/register_file/")
def register_file(
    file_name: Path,
    search_criteria: Union[int, str],
    db: Session = our_db,
):
    db_entry = get_db_entry(file_name=file_name, search_criteria=search_criteria, db=db)


Thank you so much! I can confirm that this tweak you suggested solved my query! In the interest of learning, may I ask why that makes such a big difference? Is the default version of our_db not the same as the one explicitly referred to?

You can use Depends in the signatures of endpoints or dependencies\sub-dependencies. In that case FastAPI will solve them (execute function end use its result as a value of function parameter). But in your case get_db_entry is neither endpoint function nor dependency\sub-dependency. It's just a function you call during the execution of endpoint. So, Depends is useless there. You should pass the values of parameters explicitly

Thanks for clarifying why Depends is not the right choice for this variable. I think I understand that bit now. :D Building on from that, may I know what causes the our_db parameter to behave so differently when it is used as a default value (db=our_db) vs when it is passed explicitly?

Since your out_db equals to Depends(our_db_session), db=our_db is equal to db=Depends(our_db_session). But as I said before, you can't use Depends here since it's neither an endpoint function nor a dependency function.

Oh, so is it the case that when I pass it explicitly to the get_db_entry() function in the decorated functions, it uses an instance of it that has been properly handled by FastAPI?

Yes! FastAPI solves this dependency for register_file endpoint function, and then you should just pass this value to get_db_entry function

Understood! Thank you so much for your patience in explaining what is going on under the hood in approachable terms!
